# ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have an sql request:

```
SELECT LEFT("Libelle", 10) as lib, round(sum("Montant_fac_eur")) from "foundry_sync"."/Users/Data/detfactsam16_17_Données-master" 

group by lib, round
```

It return this error:

```
ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY
```

Please where's my fault ?
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using 'round' in group by?

Comment: Thanks @Just_Do_It ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove 'round' from group by clause, no need for that.

```
SELECT LEFT("Libelle", 10) as lib, round(sum("Montant_fac_eur")) from "foundry_sync"."/Users/Data/detfactsam16_17_Données-master" 

group by lib
```